# Energy in chemical reactions

Tags: energy

My question concerns how energy is used in chemical reactions. I am working with a reaction between magnesium and hydrochloric acid in a class (although this is not a homework question). What I've found is that the magnesium gives away its valence electrons to either the hydrogen or to the chloride. But in the second case, the chloride ions would first give their valence electrons to the hydrogen, and then they would accept the electrons from a magnesium atom. As I was thinking about which of the cases was more probable, I started thinking about the energy involved. For example, I would think that moving the electrons first from the chloride ions to the hydrogen, and then from the magnesium to the chloride, would use much more energy than the magnesium just giving its electrons to the hydrogen ions.

My question is, as a general rule of thumb, although I wouldn't mind a detailed answer, are reactions that, like this one (as far as I know), have multiple "ways" of reacting going to take the way that uses the minimal amount of energy?  Or are the electrons free to move to whichever atom is closest?

Comment: If you dissolve a base metal in an acid, what do you get? (Hint: Chloride ions have an "octet" electron configuration.)

Comment: (Can you tell under what context you are "working" with this reaction? It is far easier to give answers if one knows a bit about the background of the audience.)

Comment: @Karl I’m a Swedish student so I’m not sure how advanced this is in terms of other courses. We are learning about salts and stuff and this is about a lab we did where we were gonna write a conclusion. Thing is, I’m quite interested in science so that takes me quite some way above what’s needed for this class, I’m just curious :)

Comment: @Karl Yeah, you get magnesium chloride :) what I’m trying to get at is if this reaction occurs a certain way, I.e. if the electrons are transferred in a certain way because it would take less energy? :)

Comment: @Karl just realized working could be interpreted as a lot of stuff, forgot to mention that it was in a class :P

Comment: Magnesium chloride (dissolved) is one thing, and the chloride was there before. What *else* do you get?

Comment: @Karl The total reaction formula would be: Mg + 2HCl —> MgCl2 + H2, so hydrogen gas

Comment: "Class" and "student" are equally widely interpretable. ;)

Comment: @Karl Problem is I don’t know what it would translate to. I am 15 years old but I’m very interested so I like stuff quite advanced :)

Comment: Aha! But that equation is not really what you did, because the whole thing was in aqueous solution. Can you change your equation to reflect that? And then, second step, simplify your equation?

Comment: @Karl Um, I can always write (aq) after the hydrochloric acid and the magnesium chloride, but that seems like cheating :) the hydrochloric acid could be written as H+ + Cl- and the magnesium chloride as Mg2+ + 2Cl-

Comment: Very good, go on! Write down the equation in full, then strike out what is the same on both sides.

Comment: @Karl so, Mg + 2H+ + 2Cl- —> Mg2+ + 2Cl- + H2. So what you mean is that the chloride ions remain unchanged but the magnesium gives away two electrons, supposedly to the hydrogen? :)

Comment: That´s it. Just as a side note: You should demand that your teacher thoroughly *explains* such basic principles. It has been shown again and again that letting students put together things on their own only works if they have already internalised the basics. You and perhaps two others of your class have got it now, the rest has likely given up about chemistry for good, like so many before them.

Answer (score 0):

Magnesium cannot give one or two electrons to the chloride ion. Because Chloride ions have the maximum number of 8 electrons in their external shells. There is no possibility for a new electron to stay on a Chloride ion. And the Chloride ion will be reluctant to accept or to loose one of its electrons, because it has the ideal conformation (8 outer electrons). So there are no "multiple ways" of reacting, as you imagine. The only thing that may happen is for magnesium to loose two electrons per atom, because at the end of this departure, it will have 8 outer electrons, and this seems to be to ultimate goal for all atoms. These electrons will be caught by $H^+$ ions, which are transformed into $H$ atoms and then into $H_2$ molecules.

Comment: Yeah, Okay :) what I meant by the chloride accepting the electron is that it would first give its electron to the hydrogen ion, but this reminded me that it might not want to do that because it already has 8 valence electrons, like the octet rule. Right?